# I need value of saved meta to display next to the post it is associated with

Tags: wp-query

This code goes on a category page. I display all the posts that belong to a specific category here, one after another. Each post has a meta box which has a drop down, so the user can select one of three images to display next to each post.

Currently, my code takes the first post and it's chosen image, but then shows this image next to all of the posts, rather than the chosen image associated with each post. I know that I need to loop through the meta values and display them next to each post. I'm not sure how I can do this in `echo EM_Events::Output( array('format'=>` which is code from a plugin I'm working with, this works exactly like `wp_query` .

My code, can anyone help please? I need to loop through the meta values in `EM_Events::Output` some how I think.

```
$latest_cpt = get_posts("post_type=event&numberposts=1"); 
$theidone =$latest_cpt[0]->ID;
$this_post_id =  $theidone; //get_the_ID();
$key_2_value =  get_post_meta( $this_post_id, 'custom_select', true );
if( ! empty( $key_2_value )) {
    $thisisworking =   $key_2_value ;
}


echo EM_Events::Output( array('format'=>
'
<li>'.$thisisworking.'
```

Comment: Any ideas anyone, please? Or how I need to re-word my question. Any help much appreciated

Comment: Hi Tom, have you got any ideas how I can get the meta_value of a certain meta box associated with each post and show it using  `echo EM_Events::Output` which is essentially `wp_query` please? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: There isn't enough information here to answer the question, there's no information on how you're storing the data, is `custom_select` a serialised string? An ACF field? Are there multiple `custom_select` post meta on a post? Is it a string? Is it a number? Can we see the code that saves the data? Where does it come from? How does the EM_Events call end? Is this code in an admin page or a theme template, or neither? Please expand your question extensively with as many of these details and more

Comment: If you're going to use `EM_Events::Output` you'll need look through the source code to see if the Events Manager plugin author has provided any filters which will let you inject the custom field as part of the output. Your other option is to just use your own `WP_Query` loop.